# Why did Parliament set out a tribunal procedure for RROs and for recovery of prohibited payments but not for deposit protection claims?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, housing

Tenant fees act 2019 allows for recovery of prohibited payments in the relatively accessible and informal tribunal setting.

Housing Act 2004 also sets out the RRO procedure in the same accessible Tribunal venue. Yet, the very same act contains section 214 which sets out procedure for seeking penalties against landlords (with apparently the same regulatory objective as RROs) defines it as to be sought in a county court.

Why the different venue for S214 claims, despite the apparent same objectives?

Corollary: Furthermore the CPR designate these as for the more perilous part 8 procedure rather than within the comparatively friendly smell claims process.

Why would these things be so?

Are there any indications in any of the explanatory notes or Hansard reports as to the parliamentary rationale for the differing venues for these types of claims?

Comment: Could you post some relevant passages, please? It could be that everything Posted in that exposition is true, and is it fair to expect anyone but a specialist lawyer to read through two Acts to be sure of that?